# How can I obtain the component if I know the ID of the DOM element?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I just inherit an ExtJS application that has a lot of pages.  This application allows user to paste from MS Word.  In MS Word 2003, the single quotes and double quotes are not normal ASCII characters.  When the data is stored in the database, they got converted into square box or inverted question mark because our database column does not handle Unicode, and we do not want to convert the columns to handle Unicode (the data is only supposed to be ASCII, except for these quotes).  I found a JavaScript function online that would remove these quotes from a given string.

I've test this function by adding:

```
enableKeyEvents: true,
listeners: {
    keyup: function(c,e) { ... }
}
```

This works fine for one element / component.  But I have about 100 components, and with this application, it is not easy to find these components.  So what I decide to do is to listen for the keyup event on body element using jQuery:

```
jQuery('body').keyup(function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.which;
    if ((keyCode == 86) && (e.ctrlKey)) {
        var domEl = e.target;
        var domId = domEl.getAttribute('id');
    }
}
```

This application use grid components and other non-grid components as well.  To reliably get and set the value, I want to obtain the component and use its getValue() and setValue() method.  So, knowing the ID of the DOM element, is there a way to obtain the component?

Comment: Does anyone have any idea on how I can obtain the component from the ID of the element, or any suggestions on how I can solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you have domId try with

```
var objComp = Ext.getCmp(domId);
```

if you are using any layout try

```
var objComp = Ext.getCmp('center-region').getComponent(domId)
```